# VSCode ACI deployed Docker containers not showing in sidebar

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, azure-container-instances

I am new to working with containers, and was doing the docker/vscode tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/docker/tutorials/deploy-to-cloud).

The following issue has arisen during deployment (Step 9 of tutorial):

**Containers deployed to Azure Cloud Instances do not show up in the sidebar.**

Instead it says: "Failed to connect. Is Docker running?" and "Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established"

This is counterintuitiv, as deployment via VScode actually worked.

Docker seems to be correctly installed:

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61
```

and the container is running:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND             STATUS              PORTS
agitated-newton     leopkcode/getting-started                       Running             <IP>:<PORT>
```

**so why are running container instances not showing up in the left sidebar of the Docker extension?**

I am running VSCode on WSL2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Nancy Xiong, the issue must have been related to the local Docker installation. The exact nature is unclear, as I had made sure that both Docker engine and Docker Desktop were installed and running. Nonetheless:

**Re-installing Docker Desktop Desktop (not Docker Engine) did solve the issue.**

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this issue, the problem is that your docker engine or Docker Desktop on Windows is not running. See [Install Docker Desktop on Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/).

[image]

Once the docker desktop is running and refreshes the containers in the VS docker extension. The ACI will display in the left sidebar of the Docker extension.

[image]

Comment: This was not directly the solution to my issue, as Docker Desktop was already running. However, it identified the root of the problem correctly. For me **re-installing Docker Desktop** (not Docker Engine) did solve the issue.